# Check if all items in a list are true

Tags: haskell, logical-operators

I'm working through [Programming in Haskell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521692695) and was asked the following:

> Decide if all logical values in a list are true.

I sketched some things on paper and wound up with:

```
listand     ::  [Bool] -> Bool
listand []              = True
listand (x:xs)  
    | x == False        = False
    | otherwise         = listand xs
```

All the while thinking, okay I know I'm traversing the list correctly, but how do I keep track of the True values (yeah, I'm probably thinking too much like an imperative mind in a functional world).

Anyway, I ran the code and it was correct. But I've never told it how to behave when it found a true value.

So I made the same thing for OR:

```
listor      ::  [Bool] -> Bool
listor []               = False
listor (x:xs)
    | x == True         = True
    | otherwise         = listor xs
```

And sure enough this works as well.

Now my question is, why does it work? Since I've never told it to use True in case of the listand function, how does this work exactly? Is this because of the guard clause?

Comment: Well, `otherwise` of `False` is `True`, right?

Comment: Yeah, sure enough. It's just I never told it to 'put out True' explicitly, like I did with the 'x == False'  case. Maybe its just a stupid question hehe

Comment: Oh wait... Where is the definition for an empty list?

Comment: Yeah, that will fail, mind you I was just sketching up at this stage

Comment: and that is why your sketch will not work (and will not produce `True` ever) - try it with `[]` or `[True]`, ... how did your run this code to produce `True`?

Comment: It does produce true (at least in Hugs)

Comment: with what input? (the first version has not even a correct syntax as a `=` is missing - so you probably did not give us the version you tested against)

Comment: Main> listand [True, True, True]
True

Comment: I found the error... auch recursive call to 'and' /cry

Comment: well I have no hugs around to try this but this would be really suprising - are you sure you gave us the right version? Because i GHC(i) it will produce a "Non-exhaustive patterns" exception - which is to be expected ... well ok

Comment: Yeah, I'm so sorry, a stupid error on my part :'(

Comment: I hate to let you cheat on learning, but the `all` and `any` functions accomplish this too :)

If you're interested in folds, try implementing them with `foldr`!

Comment: Yeah sure, but these are just exercises given by the author. I know I could use 'foldr (&&) True xs ' as well

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, yes, your code works because of the guard clause. This is because of how lists work in Haskell.

Internally, Haskell lists are linked lists. In short, this means that a list item is either the empty list, or a pair of a thing and another list.

To make this concrete, here's an example.

The list `[5,10,15]` is a pair of `5` and the list `[10,15]`.

The list `[10,15]` is a pair of `10` and the list `[15]`.

The list `[15]` is a pair of `15` and the empty list `[]`.

This list can also be written as `5:10:15:[]`, and this is where the pattern `(x:xs)` comes from.

This should make it clear how your function works. A list with some items will match the `(x:xs)` pattern. If none of the list items are `False`, the function keeps executing on the rest of the list, until the rest of the list is just the empty list, at which point it matches the `[]` pattern and you get your final answer.